Toolbar height changes when changing the tint of a navigation Split View
With this simple view in iOS 17.6.1 on a 13" iPad there is this bug where when the sidebar is expanded the height of the toolbar is different than when it is closed.
It does not reproduce in simulators but does reproduce in 17.7.1.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var columnVisibility: NavigationSplitViewVisibility = .detailOnly
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibility) {
            Text("Sidebar")
        } detail: {
            NavigationStack {
                Group {
                    Text("Body")
                }
                /*.toolbar {
                    presentationToolbar
                }*/
                .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
            }

            .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbarBackground(.white, for: .navigationBar)
        }
        .tint((columnVisibility == .detailOnly) ? .gray : .purple)
    }
}

Is there anyway to workaround this?


It may already be fixed in newer versions of the OS. This does not reproduce on iOS 18.1 on a 12.9" iPad Pro (5th Gen).
You might consider using XCode's "Debug View Hierarchy" to explore the differences between those 2 states. Maybe some less-obvious items in the hierarchy are larger when the sidebar is hidden? Does the sidebar button get pushed offscreen when the bar moves up?
You may also want to look for already-filed bugs against the control(s). Seems like there've been a few in this area.
